# How disable acl for all entities in loopback?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

Every model has `acls` section in json which can be removed for disabling `acl` for concrete entity. Can `acl` be disabled for all entities in one place (in model-config, may be)?

P.S. I have tried to remove `ACL` from `model-config.js` but got

```
 Unhandled error for request GET /api/path: Error: Cannot call ACL.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable ACLs completely, remove server/boot/authentication.js, which should contain something like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function enableAuthentication(server) {
  // enable authentication
  server.enableAuth();
};
```

That alone should be enough to simply disable ACLs. But if you fully want to remove them I would recommend cleaning up any ACL configuration as well:

1. In server/model-config.json, remove the `"ACL"` section. For example:

   ```
   "ACL": {
     "dataSource": "db",
     "public": false
   },
   ```
2. In each .json file in server/models, remove the `"acls"` section. For example:

   ```
   "acls": [
     {
       "accessType": "WRITE",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "$everyone",
       "permission": "DENY"
     }
   ],
   ```
3. In the database, remove the `ACL` table